# Google analytics doesn't work for Vaadin 7 RC2

Tags: google-analytics, vaadin

This issue is driving me crazy. I just tried to make Vaadin 7 RC2 application to be tracked by google analytics and seems I'm dead in the water.

I checked it definitely runs the following script:

```
 public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        WebApplication.getInstance().logout();
        flowControllerContextLoader.load(ApplicationContextLocator.getApplicationContext());

        eventProcessor.init(ApplicationContextLocator.getWebFlowConfiguration());
        eventProcessor.run(flowController);

        applicationLayout.setCaption(Translations.APPLICATION_NAME);
        setContent(applicationLayout.getView());
        getPage().setTitle(messageSource.getMessage(Translations.APPLICATION_NAME));


        JavaScript.getCurrent().execute(
        "var _gaq = _gaq || [];\n" +
                "  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'platform.lexaden.com']);\n" +
                "  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'ACCOUNT_INFO']);\n" +
                "  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);\n" +

                "\n" +
                "  (function() {\n" +
                "    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;\n" +
                "    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';\n" +
                "    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);\n" +
                "  })();\n");

    }
```

But google analytics show nothing. Could anyone please help me out?

Now hopefully it's started working.
I cleaned up the cache, recompiled application once again and all widgets with Vaadin 7 RC2 and restarted server. 
Still not sure what's wrong - probably some conflict somewhere in cache between Vaadin 6 and Vaadin 7 applications.

Comment: Is platform.lexaden.com your live domain ? Because I looked at that domain with a javascript debugger and it does not send any info to google (the ga.js file is there but _trackPageview etc is missing - maybe there is a problem with your function after all).

Comment: Yes platform.lexaden.com is alive. For me this script sounds as correct one since it works just fine with another Vaadin application. Both applications are run on the same server. Maybe the problem with cache somewhere...will try to figure out

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me google analytics sometimes cannot recognize domains. As far as I understand you are tracking **platform.website.com** and **somethingelse.website.com** and it works for one of them and doesn't work for second one or vice versa.

In this case create a separate 'track' in google analytics for **platform.website.com**. Hope it will help.

Comment: I made it work in a separate track and now it works just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the GoogleAnalyticsTracker add-on for Vaadin? https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/googleanalyticstracker

Although the add-on's page says it's for version 6.x only, I wonder if it can actually be made work with Vaadin 7.

Comment: That add-on does not work in Vaadin 7 because it uses the old API:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.terminal.PaintTarget

PainTarget is now in a new package.